# C#: Getting value via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

i would like to know if it's possible to do something like this:

```
class brand
{
  string name;
}

class car
{
   string carname;
   brand carbrand;
}
```

now i've got a string like this and an instantiated object of the type car:

```
 car carobject = new car();
 string brandNameOfCar = DoSomeMagicalReflectionStuff(car, "car.brand.name");
```

How would the "DoSomeMagicalReflectionStuff" method look like?

And is it even possible to do something like:

```
 car carobject = new car();
 string brandNameOfCar = DoSomeMagicalReflectionStuff(car, "car.brand.name.ToFormatedString()");
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just use carobject.carbrand.name ?

Comment: Because this is just a stupid example and in the "real application" i want the flexibility of accessing any entity like that

Comment: I would like to do some "templating" like this and need to have access  to explicit entity-informations from just a string like the one above.

Comment: This looks like truly BAD design.

Comment: @Jan: Why is that? It seems he wants to implement some kind of DSL, and there is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually don't try to plug products I'm involved in, but this is a perfect problem to be solved by [Vici Parser](http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/parser/home) (open source expression parser for .NET):

```
var parser = new CSharpParser();
var context = new CSharpContext();

context["car"] = carobject;

string brandNameOfCar = 
          parser.Evaluate<string>("car.brand.name.ToFormatedString()", context);
```

Comment: An overkill for something easily implemented with the bcl of .net if you ask me

Comment: @Rune: you don't really know the reasons why he wants something that evaluates expressions stored in a string. I personally use dynamic expression parsing a lot for creating very simple DSL solutions.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't test this, but here's something that should work:

```
car c = new car();
object val = typeof(car).GetField("carbrand", BindingFlags.Private).GetValue(c);
string result = (val as brand).ToFormattedString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Typeof(car).GetProperty("brand", bindingflags.instance |  bindingflags.private).GetValue(carobject,null)
should so it. Sry for minor syntax errors bit im on my phone

edit: the above Will give you the brand object and you Can the dó the same to get to the name property

Answer (score 0):

Would it make more sense to have a constructor of car that takes a string as a parameter and does something like the following:

```
class brand
{
    public string name;
}

class car
{

    public car(string s)
    {
        Match match = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<carname>[^\.]+)\.(?<brandname>.+)");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            this.carname = match.Groups["carname"].Value;
            this.carbrand = new brand();
            this.carbrand.name = match.Groups["brandname"].Value;
        } else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid car");
        }
    }

    string carname;
    brand carbrand;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return carname + "." + carbrand.name;
    }
}
```

With the following use:

```
car c = new car("M5.BMW");
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
```

You could off course separate it into a Parse and TryParse method.

Comment: Wow, someone should take your keyboard holder licence away from you ! Why a string ? why parsing it ? why not 2 arguments ? o_O

Comment: Because the question was passing in a string, for example if it was parsing a file from somewhere which had many cars.

Comment: Although in your favor, the standard is to not have a constructor with a string like that, but a Parse method instead.